# Measure output AC voltage and current from a DC/AC inverter

Tags: measurement, inverter

As the title, I'm trying to measure and display 230VAC voltage and current from a DC/AC inverter on an oscilloscope. I don't know if I can proceed to measure them directly with these equipment:

-Oscilloscope: Tektronix TPS 2014b

-Differential Probe: TT-SI 9001 with the range of +-700V at 1/100 (CAT 3 1000 Vrms)

-Current Clamp: Fluke i30s with max current of 20 Arms

The inverter is pure sine Phoenix inverter 12|250. Power: 250VA and Peak power of 400W.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry for not stating it out. The question is: Can I proceed to measure with such equipment?

Comment: Because measuring and displaying AC on an oscilloscope usually need some protection such as isolation transformer or a voltage divider. However, because I also have the mentioned probes, I don't know if I can measure the output directly on the oscilloscope via these probes.

Comment: Show schematic.